# Output returns generated expression instead of list

Tags: python, string

I am trying to perform pre processing steps on a large dataset where each row is a document. Currently my output keeps spitting out a generated expression...It is meant to return a list of words. Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
import string
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import *
import csv
import numpy as np


articles = pd.read_csv("news-train.csv", encoding ='utf-8', header = 0)
#stemming tool from nltk
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
# a mapping dictionary that help remove punctuations
remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None)for char in string.punctuation)

def get_tokens(text):
  for x in text.iterrows():
    lowers = [x.lower() for x in text]
    no_punctuation = [lowers.translate(remove_punctuation_map) for lowers in text]
    tokens=[nltk.word_tokenize(no_punctuation) for no_punctuation in text]
    filtered = [w for w in tokens if not w in stopwords.words('english')]

    stemmed = []
    for item in filtered:
        stemmed.append(stemmer.stem(item) for item in text)
    return stemmed
    

u = get_tokens(articles)
```

Comment: You probably meant `extend` instead of `append`, although you might have meant `append(list(...))` - try them both and see the difference

Comment: First of all: what do you need the outer `for x` loop for? It returns after first iteration and `x` is never used.

Comment: I am trying to get it to loop over each row (that is each document) if that makes sense.@Mafor

Comment: i tried the extend and append(list(..) both work but append(list(..) works better..the code now only outputs the first row (cleaned)..ther are 1490 rows in the dataset but only the first row is outputed.any ideas? @mafor

Comment: append(list(..) works better!! Thank you @alani!

Comment: I want it to loop over every row and return output for every row not just the first iteration

Comment: @Kaosi Your `return` statement is inside the outer `for` loop - reduce the indentation of the `return` (so that it starts in the same column as the `for`).

Comment: @alani..i tried that but it outputs the first row three times instead of the other rows in the dataset

Comment: It does not seem to go through the other rows. its stuck on the first row which happens to be where the headings are for the columns are.@alani